# Dynamically increase and decrease row height ng grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I want to increase row height of ng-grid. For example if my cell content increase to more then 3 lines then I want to show a button and then after click on that button the row size increase and show the remaining content of the cell. I am new in angular js so kindly help me. I also try this plugin but it wont work in my case.

Comment: see plunker link of that plugin http://plnkr.co/edit/tfS4Jce9XNRvM6hKqKq0?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This will not work with ng-grid since it simulates a table by positioning divs in a grid manner. So if you try to increase the height of a row, you have to readjust the top positions of all following rows (eg. cell-like divs) which is simply not in the code.

Better look out for a `table` based solution like [ng-table](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/1) which has all the fancy features of ng-grid, like sorting, filtering, pagination etc.

Since the structure is based on the browsers native table functions you can leave the proper calculation of dynamic row heights to it's way more powerful rendering engine.

Just look around, there are more than one powerful directives for tables.